# isEqualToString returns false for identical strings?

Tags: ios, objective-c

Maybe I'm going nuts, but I can't seem to understand why isEqualToString is returning false in this case.

I have written the following method to decode strings from percent encoded URL:

```
-(NSString*) decodeFromURLSafe: (NSString*) urlToDecode{
    NSString *safeUrl = [urlToDecode stringByReplacingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    safeUrl = [safeUrl stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceCharacterSet]];
    return safeUrl;
}
```

In practice it works, but I wrote some tests for it and don't understand why they are failing

Here's one such test:

```
-(void)testDecodingFromURLSafe{
    NSString *unescapedString = @"@a!b*c(d)e;f:g&h=i+j$k,l/m#n\\p[q]r<s>t^u{v}w|x~y";
    NSString *answer = [_viewController decodeFromURLSafe:@"%40a%21b%2Ac%28d%29e%3Bf%3Ag%26h%3Di%2Bj%24k%2Cl%2Fm%23n%5C%5Cp%5Bq%5Dr%3Cs%3Et%5Eu%7Bv%7Dw%7Cx%7Ey"];
    NSLog(@"%@", answer);
    NSLog(@"%d", [answer isEqualToString:@"@a!b*c(d)e;f:g&h=i+j$k,l/m#n\\p[q]r<s>t^u{v}w|x~y"]);
    XCTAssert([answer isEqualToString:unescapedString], @"decoding works");
}
```

The string in the second NSLog statement is copied directly from the output of the first:

```
2014-11-20 14:03:46.352 ProjName[5573:60b] @a!b*c(d)e;f:g&h=i+j$k,l/m#n\\p[q]r<s>t^u{v}w|x~y
```

But both the comparisons return false and I'm confused as to what I'm missing.
I've tried putting the string into DiffNow to double check that they're identical and still nothing.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to double your backslashes, so that they escape correctly:

`@a!b*c(d)e;f:g&h=i+j$k,l/m#n\\\\p[q]r<s>t^u{v}w|x~y`

Comment: That's actually why there are two. Its supposed to only be one

Comment: Actually with your answer I just realized I still put both slashes in the percent encoded one. Thanks!!!